# RMI implementation Java

Tags: java, rmi

I want to implement a simple RMI application with Java.

Here is my classes;

RMIInterface;

```
public interface RMIInterface extends Remote
{
     String translate ( String wordInTurkish ) throws RemoteException ;
}
```

RMIImplementation;

```
public class RMIImplementation implements RMIInterface
{
    @Override
    public String translate ( String wordInTurkish )
    {
        if ( wordInTurkish.equalsIgnoreCase( "Merhaba" ) )  { return "Hello" ; }
        if ( wordInTurkish.equalsIgnoreCase( "..."     ) )  { return "..."   ; }

        return "Not found in the dictionary" ;
    }
}
```

RMIServer;

```
public class RMIServer
{
    public static void main ( String args[] ) throws Exception
    {
         String codebase = "http://localhost:8080/rmi/" ;
         String name     = "RMIInterface"               ;
         System.setProperty( "java.rmi.server.codebase" , codebase ) ;
         RMIImplementation obj  = new RMIImplementation();
         RMIInterface      stub = (RMIInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject( obj , 0 );
         LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2020).bind(name, stub);
    }
}
```

RMIClient;

```
public class RMIClient
{
    public static void main ( String args[] ) throws Exception
    {
        String host = "localhost"    ;
        String name = "RMIInterface" ;       
    }
}
```

How can I implemet the RMIClient and is there anything wrong in other parts?

Comment: you can have a look here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/

Comment: have you looked into RMI tutorial sample which comes together with JDK?

Comment: (Nothing to do with RMI, but as you probably know the Turkish group of languages have issues with case (particularly with the letter 'i').)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    RMIInterface cl = (RMIInterface) new InitialContext().lookup("rmi://localhost:2020/RMIInterface");
    String res = cl.translate("xxx");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RMIInterface remote = (RMIInterface ) 
LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost",8080).lookup("RMIInterface");
remote.translate("merhaba");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 serverAddress=127.0.0.1
 rmiRegistiry=rmi://127.0.0.1/DanBankServer

 Registry locateServerRegistery = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverAddress);
 System.out.println("Server Registery is  been looked up for address: "+rmiRegistiry);
 SekelatonInterface danBankServer = (SekelatonInterface) locateServerRegistery.lookup(serverRmiUrl);
```